# Python append to same file from multiple machines

Tags: python, file-io, cluster-computing

I'm using a computing cluster to handle thousands of jobs which ought to append their output to a specific set of files on a shared storage device.
It's important to note that they only *append*, not read nor write, and that the order is not important.

Would this cause any trouble with appending to the same file at the same time, or would something like that be properly handled by a Python IO buffer or by the filesystem itself? I'm using

Because I need to separate my jobs over different cores/machines, (I think?) it is not possible to write to some common queue as one would do when doing a multithreaded calculation on a single machine (which is in essence a single job).

Comment: For such environment I would suggest writing into a simple SQLite Database. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1):

You can open the same file twice in `a` (append) mode and write to it without problems. The Python instance that closes the file first, will have its effect applied to the file first. This is regardless of which instance opens the file first or calls `.write()` first.

Example (in chonological order):

```
Console 0:
>>> f=open('test', 'w+')
>>> f.write("line 1")
>>> f.close()

Console 1:
>>> f=open('test', 'a')
>>> f.write("I opened and wrote first\n")

Console 2:
>>> f=open('test', 'a')
>>> f.write("I closed first\n")
>>> f.close()

Console 1:
>>> f.close()

Console 0:
>>> f=open('test', 'r')
>>> f.readlines()
['line 1\n', 'I closed first\n', 'I opened and wrote first\n']
```

Comment: This will work as long all write commands do not write at the same time. If it happens you will get something like `I openedosed first\nand wrote first\n` in the output I believe.